# how to remove element with HTML Quick form?

Tags: php, html

In a project I have to use HTML Quick forms to create elements.
I have created checkbox element with name hobbies[]. When I the form is posted I do get the array of hobbies and their values and would display the same form again.

Now I want to remove those checkboxes which were not selected.
Basically in HTML Quick forms you can use $form->removeElement('elementname'). But as the checkboxes are array, if i try to use the above code its removing only the first checkbox.

Is there a way to remove only those checkboxes which were not selected.

Hope I have explained clearly. If not please let me know, I'll try to elaborate bit more.

Thanks,
Tanmay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
As you have the selected check boxes in an array. on refreshing, you should  have display check boxes with condition

```
 if(check box is checked)
```

display check box of that array only. what 
 i mean is generate html for check box with the selected array

else

default html , with all the values.

But , let me ask you one thing. Let assume there are 10 check box , he select 5 , if you show only that 5  , and if he want to add one more check box , how can the user add , because you are not at all displaying. May be in your case its not needed...

Comment: Yes as per the needs the checkboxes are not needed once he selects few of them. But yes your suggestion did the trick for me.